# Entity Framework Core 1.0.0: Eager loading with Where-clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

When I used EntityFramework 7.0.0-rc1 I wrote something like this:

```
context.MyEntity
.Include(e=>e.MySubEntities)
.Where(e=>e.MySubEntities.Contains(value))
.Where(e=>e.Status==1)
.ToList();
```

In EFCore 1.0.0 the same code throws an exception. I suppose the `Include` at the moment the first `Where` runs hasn't loaded the data. So now I need first instantiate my collection with all related data then query it.
Previous approach seemed to be optimized since there was the only database query (wasn't it?). How can I do the same now?

P.S. I'm using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 1.0.0

Comment: are you using EFCorce 1 RTM?

Comment: @Nils Yes. `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",     "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },`

Comment: Well, it should work - according to the official documentation: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html

Comment: Only thing i can think of, if MySubEntities.Contains(value) - when value is an object, it may be necessary to include it too via .ThenInclude().

Comment: @Nils I saw this. Might the problem could be related with EF driver for PostgeSQL?

Comment: @Nils No, There are no related data of MySubEntity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116463/discussion-between-nils-and-slip).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Contains in EF Core like that because the value cannot not be translated in the expression tree:

Just use it like that:

```
 var tmp = myConext.MyEntity
          .Include(e=>e.MySubEntities)
          .Where(x => x.MySubEntities.Select(id=>id.MySubEntitiesId).Contains(value.MySubEntitiesId))
          .Where(e=>e.Status==1)
          .ToList();
```